# Store a value in a string type field which stores value as an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I am creating a rake take for multiple attachment import and the only issue that I am not able to figure-out is how to store the filename in the documents field as it stores the filename name as an array.

This is what I am try to do,

upload.rake

```
require 'fileutils'
namespace :request_document do
  desc "Expects to get a file or folder ..."
  task :import_attachment, [:filename] => [:environment] do |task, args|

    source_directory = "/Users/admin/Documents/demo"

    Dir.foreach(source_directory) do |filename|
      if /^(?<client_id>\d+)/ =~ filename
        puts filename
        client = Client.find_by(
          legacy_client_id: client_id
        )
        if client.nil?
          puts "Client Not Found"
        else
          puts "Client found"
          request = client.requests.last
          # document_uploader = DocumentUploader.new
          # File.open("#{source_directory}/#{filename}") { |f| document_uploader.store!(f) }
          # document_uploader.store!("#{source_directory}/#{filename}")
          target_directory = "public/uploads/request/documents/#{request.id}"
          puts request.id
          FileUtils.mkdir_p(target_directory)
          FileUtils.cp("#{source_directory}/#{filename}", "#{target_directory}")
          request.documents.push(['filename'])
          request.save
        end
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

schema for request

```
create_table "requests", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "documents", default: [], array: true
end
```

I am using carrierwave gem for multiple image upload.

The error I am getting is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `identifier' for ["filename"]:Array
```

Comment: Are you using Postgres which has a native array type? Otherwise you need to use [serialize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize). But I would consider using a separate table and setting up an association instead as its a better design (or using ActiveStorage which does this).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this once with carrierwave before. It took me forever to figure it out, but there was some duplication between the model attribute and the carrierwave mount point. There's a closed issue on the carrierwave repo referencing it [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1581#issuecomment-84324051)